# Why am i not able to show more than one widget in mainwindow?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created two custom widgets using pyqt5. I want to show both of them in my mainwindow.But the problem is that only any one of them is showing up.Only the object which is being created at second number is visible.

```
class Mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
     xfactor = 0.0
     yfactor = 0.0
     windetails = []

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        # self.setupUi(self)
        self.setresolutionparams()
        self.setupobject()



    def setresolutionparams(self):
        desk = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget()
        self.xfactor = desk.width()/1600.0;
        self.yfactor = desk.height()/900.0;
        print(self.xfactor)

    def setupobject(self):

        self.windetails.append((int)(1130 * self.xfactor))
        self.windetails.append((int)(732 * self.yfactor))
        self.windetails.append((int)(470 * self.xfactor))
        self.windetails.append((int)(160 * self.yfactor))
        pepwin_ = pepwin(self)
        pepwin_.setupwindow(self.windetails,self.xfactor,self.yfactor)
        pepwin_.setbtncnfg(3,3,self.windetails[2], self.windetails[3])
        pepwin_.settext(1,1,"Select\nFiles")
        pepwin_.settext(3, 3, "Exit")
        pepwin_.show()

        self.windetails.clear()
        self.windetails.append(0.0)
        self.windetails.append(0.0)
        self.windetails.append(1600.0 * self.xfactor)
        self.windetails.append(50.0 * self.yfactor)
        scrntitle_ = screentitle(self)
        scrntitle_.setupwindow(self.windetails, self.xfactor, self.yfactor)
        scrntitle_.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Mainwindow()
    window.setStyleSheet("background-color:black")
    window.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please minimize your example. You could use less code to illustrate your problem. This would improve the readers expirience and will to answer.

Answer (score 2):

When a widget is the son of a window, it is placed on top of it, in your case the second widget is placed on top of the first one. If you want to show both widgets should not overlap, a possible solution is to use a layout set in the centralwidget

```py
# ...
def setupobject(self):
    self.windetails = [
        int(1130 * self.xfactor),
        int(732 * self.yfactor),
        int(470 * self.xfactor),
        int(160 * self.yfactor),
    ]
    pepwin_ = pepwin(self)
    pepwin_.setupwindow(self.windetails, self.xfactor, self.yfactor)
    pepwin_.setbtncnfg(3, 3, self.windetails[2], self.windetails[3])
    pepwin_.settext(1, 1, "Select\nFiles")
    pepwin_.settext(3, 3, "Exit")

    self.windetails = [0, 0, 1600.0 * self.xfactor, 50.0 * self.yfactor]
    scrntitle_ = screentitle(self)
    scrntitle_.setuowindow(self.windetails, self.xfactor, self.yfactor)

    centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)
    lay.addWidget(pepwin_)
    lay.addWidget(scrntitle_)
# ...
```

Comment: Now both the widgets are visible,but their positions on the screen are not what i had given.

Comment: The problem is that the two widgets i have created have to be at specific x,y coordinates on the screen and both have different width and height.Geometry for first widget is (0,0,1600,50) and second one is (1130,720,470,160).How do i achieve that with layouts .

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation of `QDesktopWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html):

> Screen Geometry
>
> To obtain the dimensions of a particular screen, call the
>   screenGeometry() function. On some desktop environments, not all of
>   the screen is available for applications to use; for example, an
>   application dock or menu bar may take up some space. Use the
>   availableGeometry() function to obtain the available area for
>   applications.
>
> QDesktopWidget also inherits the QWidget properties, width() and
>   height(), which specify the size of the desktop. However, for desktops
>   with multiple screens, the size of the desktop is the union of all the
>   screen sizes, so width() and height() should not be used for computing
>   the size of a widget to be placed on one of the screens.

So instead of scaling the geometry of your widgets with `desk.width()` and `desk.height()` you should be scaling it with `desk.screenGeometry().width()` and `desk.screenGeometry().height()`.